# MS Project VBA: create an object with a subset of tasks

Tags: vba, ms-project

I'm writing a sub to get data from the active project's tasks. What I'm trying to do is pass a configuration parameter, and depending on that I either set my subset of tasks to what's contained in activeproject.tasks, or select a subset of tasks and add them to my new object.

My code looks like this:

```
Sub select_data_subset(config As type_ExportConfig)

Dim TaskTarget As Task
Dim TaskCollection As Tasks
Dim TaskArray As Variant
Dim counter As Integer

Select Case config.ExportType
    Case enExportAll
        Set TaskCollection = ActiveProject.Tasks
    Case enExportList
        TaskArray = Split(config.TaskList, Application.ListSeparator)
        For counter = LBound(TaskArray) To UBound(TaskArray)
            TaskCollection.Add ActiveProject.Tasks(Val(TaskArray(counter)))
        Next
End Select

End Sub
```

If my config says to export all (enExportAll is part of an enumeration I have elsewhere in the module) I create a new object identical to activeproject.tasks. If my config gives a list of items to export, what I do is pull each item from activeproject.tasks and add it to my tasks object. Then I'd pass that object to another function to do the data processing.

The problem I'm having is that I can't get the enExportList case to work. enExportAll works perfectly. But on the other one, my TaskCollection object doesn't like it when I tell it to add an object. I get "Object variable or With block variable not set". I've checked the watch on activeproject.tasks(val(taskarray(counter))) and it's returning a task object, so I have no idea why I'm getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

The [Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.tasks(object)) object is not a general-purpose collection object. It is a property of the Project object and also of the [ActiveSelection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.activeselection) object. The [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.tasks.add) method creates a new task in the project.

There are at least two options here:

1. Don't use the Tasks object and instead, loop through the tasks by looping through the array config.TaskList.
2. Use the Tasks property of the ActiveSelection object by setting a filter for the tasks you want and doing [SelectAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.selectall).

Option 1 is likely the best in this case.

Option 2 makes sense when the list of tasks is easily filtered--e.g. they already have something in common. Otherwise, the way to do it is by using a Flag field, set all tasks to False, set the Flag to True for the desired tasks and then set a filter to show just those.